# Query to check if a certain row has 2 words

Tags: mysql, sql

How to return rows where a column has 2 words (that is, strings separated by a space) in it?

It must be purely using SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name (has 2 strings in it);
```

Comment: How your two strings are going to be seprated ? What is delimiter ?

Comment: use WHERE ..REGEX..?

Comment: @CoderofCode oh sorry, with a spacebar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I dont know the names when querying. Its a big dataset. I only have to check if the name contains a spacebar basically *(from a comment)*.

If you want to distinguish names that have two parts from one-part and three-plus-part names, you can use [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name REGEXP '^[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+$'
```

This regular expression matches when the entire string consists of two non-empty parts containing no spaces, with one or more space separating them.

Answer (score 4):

**This perfectly works for me**

You can use 'AND' condition and Like Operator with wildcards (%).

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE '%Word1%' AND name LIKE '%Word2%'
```

Comment: This is simplest and best, Up voted as helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

```
...
WHERE [name] LIKE '%Word1%'
AND [name] LIKE '%Word2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE concat(' ',name,' ') like '% str1 %'
                      AND concat(' ',name,' ') like '% str2 %'
```

The extra blanks are there to separate words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following technique

```
 mysql> select length('first name')-length(replace('first name',' ','')) as diff;
    +------+
    | diff |
    +------+
    |    1 |
    +------+
```

i.e. get the difference of actual name and the name after replacing space, and if its 1 then you have the value as `firstname lastname`

So the query may look like

```
select * from table
where
length(col_name)-length(replace(col_name,' ','')) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use % between words.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col LIKE '%word1%word2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE '% %'

Comment: Hi, this would select anything with `space` . Even single space would be selected to. OP want two word.